# How to add information to devise @resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

in my rails app information about the user except email, like firstname or gender, aren't stored in the user. They can be received with a rest api from another app.

In the devise views the users information can be diplayed by the @resource variable.

How can I add informations to this variable? I think of something like ...

```
contact_from_other_app = Contact.find(@resource.contact_id_from_other_app)

@resource.firstname = contact_from_other_app.firstname
```

But where must I put that code and how exactly?

Comment: Its very unclear here what you are trying to acheive. Are you trying to fetch the additional information from the external api when the user registers and save in it your applications database? Or are you just trying to fetch the information when the user is displayed and not persist it?

Comment: Second: fetch the information when the user is displayed and not persist it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in in a few ways.

1. Delegate to association

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :contact

  delegate :firstname, :gender, to :contact, allow_nil: true
end
```

Then you can call

```
@resource.firstname # equivalent of @resource.contact&.firstname
@resource.gender    # equivalent of @resource.contact&.gender
```

2. Set attribute accessors

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :firstname, :gender
end

contact_from_other_app = Contact.find(@resource.contact_id_from_other_app)

@resource.firstname = contact_from_other_app.firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found, that I had this feature in the code already :)))

```
class Contact < OtherAppApiResource
  def firstname
    attributes["firstname"]
  end
```

In the user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def contact
    @contact ||= Contact.get(other_app_contact_id)
  end
```

Then in the view the following is possible

```
<%= @resource.contact.firstname %>
```